# Price move vs. price movement

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference, even if subtle, between **a price move** and **a price movement**? Dictionaries are of no help...

Comment: Apart from looking it up in a dictionary, what other research have you done?

Comment: Try this site:  Ludwig Guru: https://ludwig.guru/s/price+move

Comment: You should write a full sentence. Without context users can only make guesses, albeit good ones. You could also say **a movement in the price(s) of…**

Answer (score 1):

You said a dictionary was of no help. You might be using it incorrectly. Not every noun phrase is in the dictionary - there is no need when you can get the meaning from looking up the component words.

'A movement', used as a countable noun, means pretty much the same as 'a move' - that is a change of position.

But you can also use 'movement' as a non-countable noun to refer to *the act or process of moving*. It can refer to movement in general rather than a specific movement.

Therefore 'a price move' would be a specific change in the price of something, but 'price movement' would mean changes in price in general, or the concept of prices changing.

Comment: @marieclarm They could be... but I wouldn't use an article with 'price movement' unless it was just one specific move such as all the stock moved once in one direction.